# Firebase, You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | } | replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel

I'm currently on a Laravel project which uses Vue.

The project runs just fine, but when I install and use Firebase. I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/idb/build/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (83:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| }
| replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({
|     ...oldTraps,
|     get: (target, prop, receiver) => getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.get(target, prop, receiver),
|     has: (target, prop) => !!getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.has(target, prop),
 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 5:0-29
 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/app-compat/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase/compat/app/dist/esm/index.esm.js
 @ ./resources/assets/js/kyc_section.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/kyc_section.js
```

I've tried many solutions, from downgrading my node version from 16 to 14.19.0. Removing node modules and my package lock. etc.

My current node version is 14.19.0, npm 6.14.16
my package.json firebase

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^1.0.0",
        "clipboard-polyfill": "^3.0.1",
        "firebase": "^9.6.11",
```

Comment: Just to add confidence, the NodeJS version you need is `10.15.0` (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/firebase%409.6.11#verify-prerequisites) so that should not be the problem